singleton for Isolated worker model servicebus function
I have some loop that sends messages and they are processed by service bus function (isolated worker model). The function works a lot with data tables and we have troubles with it. Singleton or work in parallel presumably in not more than 3-4 messages at a time can help but how it can be done?
The number of concurrent function instances is set to 16 in the function app. But I can observe much more processes at a time.
I changed the value for maxConcurrentCalls=1 in host file and this reduced the processing of messages to 16 at a time (16 instances of function). Is it possible to reduce the number of parallel processing of messages by this function but not all func app?

However, I am not sure why the preferred solution was to go with a function app rather than a traditional listener from the design perspective. A function app is widely used for its power of scaling and performing compute/simple or fast operations at scale.
Although I have not used it personally in the past, as per the Microsoft documentation, you may be able to run it as singleton via an attribute and/or its configurations. Please check if this can help you with your requirements.
Reference Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#singleton-attribute
From the document: SingletonMode.Listener
Some triggers have built-in support for concurrency management:

QueueTrigger - Set JobHostConfiguration.Queues.BatchSize to 1.
ServiceBusTrigger - Set ServiceBusConfiguration.MessageOptions.MaxConcurrentCalls to 1.
FileTrigger - Set FileProcessor.MaxDegreeOfParallelism to 1.

